# Communicating sensitive data over fast ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

I have 3 routers that are to be directly connected using a fast Ethernet connection. Sensitive data will need to be communicated via these links.

I know that if this was a serial link then i would be able to use PPP encapsulation process with CHAP. But what are my options for a fast Ethernet connection?

Comment: What are the router models?

Comment: Cisco 2811 routers

Comment: If you have the security license, you could use encryption. By the way, CHAP doesn't actually encrypt data on the PPP link. Also, you can use PPPoE on Cisco routers.

Comment: What sort of encryption? (sorry i am just a newbie)

Comment: You can configure a site-to-site (really a router-to-router) VPN with IPsec. The IOS version you have must support this.

Comment: If you're uncertain whether a feature is supported or not:  [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp)

Comment: In what way is the data "sensitive"?  I worked on a network for the US DoD that carried Top Secret information of the US (and allies) military.  If you need that level it would be hard to describe in this forum, but I assume it's somewhat less than that.  Also, what is the **physical** connection like?  If the Ethernet they communicate on is all on your premises, there's one set of solutions, but if there are connections off premise, then there's a whole different class.

Comment: @MAP Really? MACsec (802.1AE) is hard to describe? (note: I just did.) How to set it up can be rather involved, and the 2811 doesn't support it. [http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/enterprise-networks/trustsec/trustsec_matrix.html]

Comment: @RickyBeam I'm sorry, that is not sufficiently secure for US DoD Top Secret.  Or at least it wasn't when I held a clearance and was allowed to know.

Comment: @MAP "Top Secret" covers a number of levels. MACsec meets part of those. For the highest levels, there's further encryption. (so all you'd see is yet more encrypted traffic if you managed to get past MACsec. Each layer by a different vendor, using different standards, etc. etc.)

Comment: Use ssh and exchange public keys.  It is very simple.  Works with Linux and Windows.  See my answer below.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec)

IPSec Tunnel.  You need to verify that your routers have a security feature set, or VPN capability.  If they do, IPSec VPN is the tried and true method for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

For anything sensitive, make sure you use ssh.

```
ssh keygen
ssh-copy-id -i (remote)
```

in both directions.

then you can use scp for encrypted transfers.

For Windows you can use WinSCP.  Get the PuTTY suite and look in the directory and you will find it.

This makes it simple because it can run both as scripts and as tasks.  Once you exchange public keys it will not prompt you for a password.